# Create Specific Almost-Block Matrix Structure

Tags: matrices, pspicture, a0poster, nicematrix

I am having trouble creating the following matrix. I have tried the techniques in several posts here but can't get a good result. The best option seems to be the `nicematrix` package, but I'm using the `a0poster` class and the package does not work correctly with it. I think I want `pspicture` to draw the boxes, but my result looked terrible.

[image]

The highlighting on the B's is preferred, but it doesn't have to be shaded with the diagonal lines as shown in the figure. The 0's are also nice to have, but it seems difficult to align nicely and could be ignored if necessary. The bottom "glue vectors" box really seems to mess up the alignment of the rest of the matrix.

Any code or suggestions on how to properly approach this diagram would be appreciated. Perhaps `tikz` is necessary here?

**Edit:** Below is a minimal working example of my environment. I believe the best solution is to use `nicematrix`, so I have included that. I believe the issue with this example is an incompatibility with `tikz`. I have included in the preamble some workaround code for this coming from page 21 of the `nicematrix` documentation [2](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf). I do need tikz an have included two rudimentary diagrams I need to compile in this document.

The specific error it gives me here for `nicematrix` is `The option "code-after" is unknown or meaningless in the context.` I am using TexShop 4.44 on macOS and am compiling `Tex -> DVI`. On my system (ignoring the errors) the code below appears as
[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0b,final]{a0poster}
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm, amsfonts, stmaryrd}
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\Large]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=4pt]
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\tikzset{highlight/.style={rectangle, fill=red!15, blend mode = multiply, rounded corners = 0.5 mm, inner sep=1pt, fit = #1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {pgfsys-dvips.def}
\tl_if_eq:NNT \l_tmpa_tl \pgfsysdriver
{\cs_set:Npn\pgfsys@blend@mode#1{\special{ps:~/\tl_upper_case:n 
#1~.setblendmode}}}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Definition of some variables and colors

\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%               Background                     %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\background}[3]{
\newrgbcolor{cgradbegin}{#1}
\newrgbcolor{cgradend}{#2}
\psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradend=cgradend,
gradbegin=cgradbegin,gradmidpoint=#3](0.,0.)(1.\textwidth,-1.\textheight)
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                Poster                        %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{poster}{
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.98\textwidth}
}{
\end{minipage} 
\end{center}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                pcolumn                       %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{
\begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
\begin{center}
}{
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                pbox                          %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newrgbcolor{lcolor}{0. 0. 0.80}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor1}{1. 1. 1.}
\newrgbcolor{gcolor2}{.80 .80 1.}

\newcommand{\pbox}[4]{
\psshadowbox[#3]{
    \begin{minipage}[t][#2][t]{#1} #4
    \end{minipage}
}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Begin of Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\background{0.85 0.85 0.85}{0.85 0.85 0.85}{0.5}
\vspace*{2cm}
\newrgbcolor{white}{1. 1. 1.}
\definecolor{GTgold}{RGB}{224, 170, 15}
\definecolor{GTblue}{RGB}{0, 48, 73}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.96}

\begin{poster}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Header
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\begin{pcolumn}{0.98}

\pbox{0.95\textwidth}{}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.3,linecolor=GTblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=GTgold,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}
{

%%% Left Logo
%%% Title
\begin{minipage}[c][9cm][c]{0.78\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    {\sc \Huge Minimal Working Example}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
%%% Right-Logo
}
\end{pcolumn}
\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Begin of Multicols-Enviroment

%%% Column One
\begin{pcolumn}{0.32}
\pbox{.95\textwidth}{71cm}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=GTblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=light-gray,gradend=light-gray,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{
\begin{center}
    \pbox{0.8\textwidth}{}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=GTblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=GTgold,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{
    \begin{center}
        \large {\bf Header}
    \end{center}
    }
\end{center}
\vspace{1.25cm}

%       \begin{equation*}
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}%
[margin, code-after = { \tikz \node [highlight = (1-1)] {} ; } ]
    \Block{3-3}<\Large>{A} & & & 0 \\
    & \hspace*{1cm} & & \Vdots \\
    & & & 0 \\
    0 & \Cdots& 0 & 0
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
%   \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & \cdots & \cdots & 1 \\
        0 & \ddots & & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}



}
\end{pcolumn}
%%% Column Two
\hspace{1 cm}
%\vspace{2cm}
\begin{pcolumn}{0.32}
\pbox{.95\textwidth}{71cm}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=GTblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=light-gray,gradend=light-gray,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{
\begin{center}
    \pbox{0.8\textwidth}{}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=GTblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=GTgold,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{
    \begin{center}
        \large {\bf Header}
    \end{center}
    }
\end{center}
\vspace{1.25cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % (coordinates of the bottom-left corner) "grid" (coordinates of the top right-corner)
    \draw[step=2.99cm] (-3, -3) grid (6, 0);
    \draw[step=2.99cm] (-12, -9) grid (15, -5.9);

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=20pt}] (-12, -5.8) -- (-3,-5.78); %node[midway,yshift=1em]{$m$};
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=20pt}] (-3,-5.8) -- (6,-5.8); %node[midway,yshift=1em]{$m$};
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=20pt}] (6,-5.8) -- (15,-5.8); %node[midway,yshift=1em]{$m$};

    \draw[>=latex, <->] (-7.5, -4.9) -- (-3.1, -1.5);
    \draw[>=latex, <->] (1.5, -4.9) -- (1.5, -3.1);
    \draw[>=latex, <->] (6.1, -1.5) -- (10.5, -4.9);

    \node at (-1.4, -1.45) {$x^4$};
    \node at (1.55, -1.45) {$x^3$};
    \node at (4.5, -1.69) {$x$};

    \node at (-10.5, -7.5) {1};
    \node at (-7.5, -7.5) {0};
    \node at (-4.5, -7.5) {1};
    \node at (-1.5, -7.5) {1};
    \node at (1.5, -7.5) {0};
    \node at (4.5, -7.5) {0};
    \node at (7.5, -7.5) {0};
    \node at (10.5, -7.5) {1};
    \node at (13.5, -7.5) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

}
\end{pcolumn}
%%% Column Three
\hspace{1.75 cm}
\begin{pcolumn}{0.32}
\pbox{.95\textwidth}{71cm}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=GTblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=light-gray,gradend=light-gray,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{
\begin{center}
    \pbox{0.8\textwidth}{}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=GTblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=GTgold,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{
    \begin{center}
        \large {\bf Header}
    \end{center}
    }
\end{center}
\vspace{1.25cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % (coordinates of the bottom-left corner) "grid" (coordinates of the top right-corner)
    \draw[step=2.99cm] (-9, -6) grid (9, 6);
    \draw[dashed, GTgold] (-3.2, 6.2) -- (0.2, 6.2) -- (0.2, -6.2) -- (-3.2, -6.2) -- cycle;
    \draw[dashed, violet] (-9.2, 3.2) -- (9.2, 3.2) -- (9.2, -0.2) -- (-9.2, -0.2) -- cycle;
    \node at (-10.8, 1.5) {\color{violet} Inner};
    \node at (-1.5, 7.5) {\color{GTgold} Outer};
\end{tikzpicture}

}
\end{pcolumn}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You say you have tried something, so please post a complete compilable code of what you have.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem, especilaly just the text portion (ignoring the drawing). If you can do that then it should be relatively simple for someone to use `\tikzmark` to do the drawings.  Bascially, show what you can do and save those trying to help you from having to do that work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was debating a MWE but there's nothing minimal about an a0poster and I really wasn't close so... I have edited the question now to include one.

Comment: @elsinc89: Ok,  but I don't see any reason to use the `a0poster` class for figuring out how to do this drawing. You could just use `article` class for the MWE so that focus is on drawing the desired diagram.

Comment: @PeterGrill I am using `a0poster` in my example because I believe the problem here is the incompatibility of this class with the matrix packages which could make this work. If I made a demo in `article`, it might not port over to what I really need it for. I might very well be mistake though.